# How to add animation to rubymotion applications?

Tags: ios, core-animation, rubymotion

Im currently adding animations to buttons and view like

```
            @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
            @button.frame = [[0,0],[50,50]]
            @button.setTitle("Click to move",forState:UIControlStateNormal)
            @button.addTarget(self, action:'animate_button',forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview @button 

      def animate_button
            @button.frame = [[0,0],[0,0]]
            UIView.beginAnimations(nil,context:nil)
            UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.05)
            UIView.setAnimationDelay(0.2)
            UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut)
            @button.frame = [[280,400],[50,50]]
            UIView.commitAnimations
     end
```

can anyone help to use advanced animations

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at sugarcube?  It is very popular - along with BubbleWrap, it's one of the most used gems for rubymotion.  It has a growing collection of animation-related methods, and uses the new block syntaxes (like what Paul.s mentions)

The most generic is `UIView.animation { animations_go_here }`

```rb
UIView.animation {
  my_view.frame = new_frame
  # or apply a transform to a layer
  my_view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 1)
}
```

see [Core Animation Function Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreAnimation_functions/Reference/reference.html) for more transform functions.

But if you want to do a "common" animation, you can do a lot with some UIView additions:

```rb
my_view.slide :left, 100
my_view.move_to CGPoint.new(10, 20)  # or [10, 20] works, too
my_view.fade_out
```

These all take similar options:

```rb
my_view.fade_out(duration: 1)  # 1 second fade out
my_view.fade_out(delay: 1)  # 1 second later, fade out
```

And you can chain them easily:

```rb
my_view.slide :left, 120 {
  my_view.fade_out {
    my_view.removeFromSuperview
  }
}
```

And they can be grouped:

```rb
UIView.animate {
  my_view.slide :left, 120
  my_view.fade_out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the preferred block syntax it would look like this

```
def animate_button
  @button.frame = [[0,0],[0,0]]

  animations = lambda { @button.frame = [[280,400],[50,50]] }
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay:0.05, options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut , animations:animations, completion: nil)
end
```